# Paho vs Mosquitto

Tags: embedded, mqtt

Начиная с информации, которая предоставляется при таком же "*гуглении*".
[*paho vs mosquitto*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mqtt/9P6kZznHH0I) и [*SO Paho vs Mosquitto*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039471/mosquitto-vs-eclipse-paho-client-library) - ничего конкретного не говорит. - *"Мы используем Paho, потом попробуем Mosquitto"* и тд.

При реализации обоих (тестовых `mqtt` клиентов `Paho\Mosquitto`) -  не нашел никаких трудностей с использованием\реализации\работоспособности. Все довольно понятно, удобно, гибко, secur'no (защищенно)

**Есть ли какие-то явные отличия(?)**/преимущества/подводные камни, которые я не увидел и стоит на это обратить внимание, чтобы вынести вердикт? ( `Embedded C/C++` ).
(P.S. Если явных отличий нету - зачем идет Eclipse поддержка обоих?)

Может кто-то уже имеет этот опыт. Буду признателен за любую предоставленную информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Да, у меня есть опыт. Я опишу, а вы сделаете выводы.

Я проектирую систему для мониторинга и удаленного управления ПЛК-систем. Существует достаточное количество машин (порядка тысячи), которые отправляют данные. Как всегда, данные разношерстные и используется шлюз для пересылки. Заказчик захотел JSON-файлы пересылать через эти шлюзы. Управление осущетсвляется через некий web портал с функциями администрирования. Итак, что имеем:

1. шлюзы (OpenWRT OS)
2. клиенты web портала
3. формат файлов JSON
4. какие-то данные

Как все это дело соединить вместе? MQTT брокер? А, почему бы и нет...
следовательно нам необходимо иметь клиентов mqtt. Для web неплохо подошел paho.js. Для шлюзов существует mosquitto собираемые из opkg. Ну, и сам брокер mosquitto на сервер с БД.

Тестирование и реальная нагрузка будет производиться только на следуещей неделе. Поэтому по нагрузочным тестам информации нет.

Что касается удобства. Сказать, что какой то из клиентов хуже/лучше сложно. Единственное, на данный момент времени для paho.js не поддерживается новая 5ая версия протокола mqtt. Да, это минус. Для тестирование на локальных ресурсов использовал клиентов на Python. Тоже все хорошо.

Выбор должен осуществляться исходя из поставленной задачи и ресурсов. Так думаю, самое правильное. На самом деле получается, что paho я использую только для конечных клиентов-опрераторов/администраторов. Все же остальное работает на чистом mosquitto.